# How to pass a table type to a stored procedure in a job?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a stored procedure that's called within a temporary job, so I'm doing:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_test_job
    @criteria Criteria READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @jobName nvarchar(max);
    SET @jobName = 'test';

    --Get database name
    DECLARE @dbName sysname;
    SELECT @dbName = DB_NAME();

    --Create job
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name = @jobName;

    --Create step
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
        @job_name = @jobName,
        @step_name = 'Step 1',
        @subsystem = N'TSQL',
        @database_name = @dbName,
        @command = N'EXEC my_actual_sp ' + @criteria;


    ----TODO Schedule the job at a specified date and time

    ----TODO Add the job to the SQL Server server

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = @jobName;
END
GO
```

And obviously `@command` is wrong. How can I pass the table type to my sp?

Comment: table valued parameters is what you need.  http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: @Mountaineer And that's what I'm using. But I need to pass the TVP to the command parameter of `sp_add_jobstep`.

Comment: does my_actual_sp only take one parameter?

Comment: try converting EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep into a dynamic SQL

Comment: @Mountaineer Yes. The same table type defined in this sp.

Comment: I don't think you can. `@Command` is nvarchar(max), and `@additional_parameters` is not supported. perhaps you can use a workaround such as creating an xml string from the table and work with it in the procedure.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes I was thinking about that too. Or write to an actual table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to spill the contents into a real table, and re-read that inside your job.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO PendingCriteria (/* Columns */)
SELECT /* Columns */ FROm @Criteria

...

@command = N'DECLARE @C Criteria
             INSERT INTO @C (/* Columns */) SELECT /* Columns */ FROM PendingCriteria
      EXEC my_actual_sp @C';
```

I'd then probably do the cleanup of the permanent table as a separate job step.

The problem is that jobs represent something to be done in the (for a computer) far future. Table-variables represent an object that exists solely in the here-and-now. They're also local to the session - when the job runs in the future it will be running each step in a new session.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono - xml would be another way to approach the problem. *Personally* I prefer to keep tabular data tabular, but I could see that there's less clean-up with the xml approach.